# Verify unique record in SQL server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I would like verify unique record in customer table and write the following query

```
declare @NT1 int

set @NT1 = (SELECT LogID, CustomerID, count(1)
FROM dbo.Customer
group by LogID,CustomerID
having count(1) >1)

if @NT1 > 1

print 'Fail'

ELSE  
    PRINT 'Pass';
```

I get the following message when run the query:

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

Comment: Please describe what you mean by "verify unique record in customer table".  Your code doesn't do that, and it is not clear what you mean.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I will check all LogID and CustomerID are unique and not duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If you want to verify that no `(LogId, CustomerId)` pair occurs more than once in the `Customer` table, then you can do that.

The simplest way is:

```
create unique index idxu_customer_logid_customerid on customer(logid, customerid);
```

That way, the *database* ensures uniqueness.  And, the rest of your code doesn't have to worry about it.

If you want to run your test, use `exists`:

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT LogID, CustomerID, count(1)
            FROM dbo.Customer
            GROUP BY LogID, CustomerID
            HAVING count(1) > 1
           )
   )
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Fail';
END
ELSE 
BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Pass';
END;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, The output for this query is message and I am not  able to export message. Is it possible , we get output as data result?-Thanks

Comment: @Anson . . . I have no idea what you mean by "export message".  Your question uses `print`, so I have to assume that you want to print out the result.  If you have another question -- say about how to use the information in another query -- then ask another question, with sample data and an explanation of how you want to use the results.

Comment: Hi Gordon, I want to verify if we have records meet the fail condition(HAVING count(1) > 1) and check how many records  are failed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @Ncount int

set @Ncount =  (select top 1 
 count(1) 
            FROM dbo.Customer
            GROUP BY LogID, CustomerID
                        HAVING count(1) > 0
           )

SELECT IIF ( @Ncount >= 1, 'Failed', 'Pass' ) AS Result;
```

Comment: having count(1) > 1?